# Trying to obtain an image from the flicker API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, get

I'm trying to obtain a random image from the ones retrieved from the API, I'm new to this API and can't get it to work, I've tried multiple request but none of them worked. This is my code at the moment: (That is retrieving "method not found."). (I'm using NodeJS and the snekfetch module to make the request)

```
var opts = {
    method: 'flickr.photos.search',
    api_key: '{API KEY}',
    sort: 'relevance',
    text: 'clown',
    extras: 'url_m',
    per_page: 10,
    format: 'json',
    nojsoncallback: 1
};

var file = request.get('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/').send({ opts }).then(r => console.log(r));
```

What I was expecting is that it would return an XML with the images, then I wanted to generate a random number and use that index to retrieve the image, Thank you in advanced.

Comment: have you tried not setting the format? I haven't used the Flickr API in quite some time, but I think to remember, that this is the return format, which is not JSON

Comment: Try using [`.query({ opts })`](https://snekfetch.js.org/?api=snekfetch#Snekfetch#query) rather than `.send()`. – `.send()` might only control the body the request and GET requests aren't expected to have a body.

Comment: Which NodeJS module are you using to make your request? The `.send()` syntax you're using isn't used by any of the most prevalent ones. Maybe try taking a look at [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: @axios I'm using snekfetch.

Comment: Didn't work @Jonathan Lonowski

Comment: Didn't work @Luca